# How to make Excel references non-absolute using REGASM32 (early binding)

Tags: excel, vba, reference, excel-addins, regasm

I have a requirement to create a new installed for an Excel add-in. I've created many of these and this question is not necessarily about the install building process. It is about how to properly reference a .dll in Excel so that it can be referenced on the receiving machine properly.

The Excel add-in references (tools/references) the file ZOPLib.dll (a .net dll of our own design). It references it in `C:\folder A`.  We used REGASM32 to register the .dll and everything works fine on the development machine. Moving the add-in over to a VM I place the ZOPLib.dll in `C:\folder B` and register it there.

Because the add-in was pointed at `C:\folder A`, even though I REGASM32 the dll, the addin fails to find it (the dll). I have to REGASM32 /uninstall the dll, REGASM32 register it in `C:\folder B` and then go into the add-in and tell it that the dll is in `C:\folder B`.

1. Why is the link to the dll absolute?
2. How can I make Excel reference this dll or register it in such a way that the add-in can find it in the new folder?
3. If I can get the .net developer of this dll to produce it as an activex dll, would that relieve my trouble?

InstallShield does not handle registering dlls that are not activex/ocx because it uses REGSVR32.

Thanks for any help!